# Simple code for phi(k) correlation matrix in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a simple way (2 or 3 lines of code) to generate a Phi(k) correlation matrix in Python.
That should be possible since pandas_profiling is doing it, and it works fine.
But I want to be able to do it without pandas_profiling which is too heavy and computes things I don't need.

pandas_profiling is using phik library.
I tried phik library (didn't find anything else)

I don't understand the error I got :
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

I have no int in my dataframe.

Seems like a bug in phik, but then how does pandas profiling do, since it's using it too ?

What's happening here ?
Many thanks

I have this code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import phik

NB_SAMPLES = 200
NB_VARIABLES = 3

rand_mat = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=15, size=(NB_SAMPLES,NB_VARIABLES))
df = pd.DataFrame(rand_mat)
df['cat_column'] = pd.cut(df[0], bins=5, labels=['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])
print(df)
df.phik_matrix()
```

Result :

```
                 0          1          2 cat_column
0     0.911098   8.549206   9.270484         F1
1    13.591250   9.161498   5.614470         F5
2     3.308305   1.589402   5.394675         F1
3    12.031064   9.968686   7.519628         F5
4    14.427813   1.533533   2.352659         F5
..         ...        ...        ...        ...
195  10.556285   3.541869   4.804826         F4
196   5.721784  11.783908  13.104844         F2
197   7.336637  14.512256  14.993096         F3
198   4.375895  11.881784   1.129816         F2
199   0.519900   6.624423   9.239070         F1

[200 rows x 4 columns]
interval_cols not set, guessing: [0, 1, 2]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 608, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/phik/phik.py", line 162, in _calc_phik
    combi = ':'.join(comb)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-398c72b34799> in <module>
     11 df['cat_column'] = pd.cut(df[0], bins=5, labels=['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])
     12 print(df)
---> 13 df.phik_matrix()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/phik/phik.py in phik_matrix(df, interval_cols, bins, quantile, noise_correction, dropna, drop_underflow, drop_overflow)
    215     data_binned, binning_dict = bin_data(df_clean, cols=interval_cols_clean, bins=bins, quantile=quantile, retbins=True)
    216     return phik_from_rebinned_df(data_binned, noise_correction, dropna=dropna, drop_underflow=drop_underflow,
--> 217                                  drop_overflow=drop_overflow)
    218 
    219 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/phik/phik.py in phik_from_rebinned_df(data_binned, noise_correction, dropna, drop_underflow, drop_overflow)
    145 
    146     phik_list = Parallel(n_jobs=NCORES)(delayed(_calc_phik)(co, data_binned[list(co)], noise_correction)
--> 147                                         for co in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(data_binned.columns.values, 2))
    148 
    149     phik_overview = create_correlation_overview_table(dict(phik_list))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1015 
   1016             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1017                 self.retrieve()
   1018             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1019             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    907             try:
    908                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 909                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    910                 else:
    911                     self._output.extend(job.get())

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    560         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    561         try:
--> 562             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    563         except LokyTimeoutError:
    564             raise TimeoutError()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    433                 raise CancelledError()
    434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 435                 return self.__get_result()
    436             else:
    437                 raise TimeoutError()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: It works for me on `phik.__version__ =='0.10.0'`.

Comment: It works for you?

Comment: I was using version 0.9 (which is installed by default on kaggle with pip.  I used conda to install version 0.10.0 and now it works)

Comment: How should I accept your answer, to close the question ?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Comment: Forgot to accept (and possibly upvote) the answer?

Comment: As an FYI for anyone looking to export the tabular matrix from `pandas_profiling` here is how: `profile.get_description()['correlations']['phi_k']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall the `phik` module as the following:

```
pip install phik==0.10.0
```

Then, your code together with `sns.heatmap` results the following:

[image]

Comment: i don't get why it does't go from -1 to 1?